# can't get variable from an empty game object with script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm trying to get variable from an empty gameObject's script, but I can't assign that gameObject on the inspector. These are the screen shots and codes from my game.

Well, I have this code to load when the game is starting. Land and Prince are objects that made from this code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;


public class loadGame : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static loadGame loadSave;

    public GameObject objPrince;
    public Pangeran charPrince;
    public Transform prefPrince;

    public Sprite[] spriteTanah;
    public Dictionary<string, Tanah> myTanah = new Dictionary<string, Tanah>();
    public Dictionary<string, GameObject>objTanah = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
    public Tanah tempTanah;
    public GameObject tempObjTanah;
    public Transform prefTanah;
    public float mapX;
    public float mapY;
    public int i = 0;
    public int j = 0;
    public int rows = 9;
    public int column = 9;
    
    void Awake(){
        if(loadSave == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            loadSave = this;
        }
        else if(loadSave != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);

    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        Load ();   
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {       
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            charPrince = new Pangeran ("Prince", "04Okt1993", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false);
            objPrince = GameObject.Instantiate (prefPrince, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            //objPrince.name = "Prince";
            charPrince.locationY = 0f;
            charPrince.locationX = 0f;
            charPrince.hadapAtas = false;
            charPrince.hadapKanan = true;
            charPrince.stamina = 100f;
            charPrince.exp = 0f;
            charPrince.speed = 0f;

            for(i = 0 ; i < rows ; i ++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j<column ; j++)
                {
                    mapX = (i-j) * 0.8f;
                    mapY = (i+j) * 0.4f;

                    if(i>=1 && j>=1 && i<=5 && j<=5)
                    {
                        prefTanah.name = "land-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#");
                        tempTanah = new Tanah("land-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),mapX,mapY,"land",spriteTanah[0],spriteTanah[1],spriteTanah[2]);
                        myTanah.Add("land-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),tempTanah);
                        tempObjTanah = GameObject.Instantiate(prefTanah, new Vector3(mapX,mapY,0),Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
                        objTanah.Add("land-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),tempObjTanah);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prefTanah.name = "snow-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#");
                        tempTanah = new Tanah("snow-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),mapX,mapY,"snow");
                        myTanah.Add("snow-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),tempTanah);
                        tempObjTanah = GameObject.Instantiate(prefTanah, new Vector3(mapX,mapY,0),Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
                        objTanah.Add("snow-"+j.ToString("0#")+"-"+i.ToString("0#"),tempObjTanah);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access one of some variables from code above, but I can't assign it in the inspector.

[image: I want to assign that code above in this code]

but I can't do it.
[image: and this is happened]

please help me. Thank you.

Comment: and you don't have this file `Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the loadLand variable is of type LoadGame which is a script. What you are trying to do is to add a GameObject to this variable. So change the public variable type to

```
public GameObject LoadLandObject;
private LoadGame loadLand;
```

and create a private LoadGame variable which is the reference to your script.
Add in the Start() method

```
loadLand = (LoadGame)LoadLandObject.GetComponent<LoadGame>();
```

With this you load the script LoadGame of the GameObject into the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever set your `plantingScript.loadLand` to the instance of `loadGame.loadSave`? This must be done after `Awake` in your case to be sure the instance has been set.

Can I ask, what are you trying to do?

You should simply just assign you loadGame script in the inspector of plantingScript and not use statics at all. They will bite your ass sooner or later (and I'm guessing it already is).

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar problem. Did n't find simple and clear solution. May be what i did help to you.

1. Create empty game object.
2. Attach loadGame.cs to it (if you whant to control when script starts - uncheck it,in this case  don't foget to set loadLand.enabled to true in plantingScript when needed)
3. Drag this object to you loadLand field

[Sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzDiq6MikW4Qc1hvdU9QV2R5MW8/view?usp=sharing)